# Using of "loading" images on the start of an Android app

Tags: android, loading

When Angry Birds starts, it has a loading page which displays images before the game starts. How can I do this? I want 2 images that can be used as advertisements and change after a short period of time before going to the main menu.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  For anyone to be able to help you, you are going to have to provide more information.  What language are you writing in? What have you tried, please post the code you have so far.  The community enjoys helping, but doesn't do whole projects.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a splash screen which displays for a period of time and then moves on. Here's one way to do it: http://www.barebonescoder.com/2010/04/a-simple-android-splash-screen/